# Toastmasters speech slot availability: what to measure?

Tags: estimation, descriptive-statistics

I belong to a new [Toastmasters](http://www.toastmasters.org/) club that is growing quickly. We meet twice a month and each meeting has four opportunities (slots) for members to give prepared speeches.

As more members vie for the available slots, we're looking at ways to respond to the demand. I figure the first step is to measure the availability of the slots.

I've automated the process of recording all available slots, polling each day. Now I'm trying to come up with a way to present the availability. My first pass is a graph showing number of days until the next free slot. But this needs refinement, and I'd appreciate your help.

One challenge is that there are effectively more free slots than it appears, since speakers sometimes give up their slot in the week before the meeting (schedule conflict or not prepared to speak). That would make my simple graph look weird.

- today: next slot in 49 days
- tomorrow: next slot in 8 days

I've also looked at measuring total number of slots available over some period… but that doesn't feel like enough guidance. I've tried finding some prior art on meeting room scheduling, which would seem similar, but no luck so far.

Comment: do you have any other in-house rules? i.e. in my club we are not allowed to more than 1 speech every 3 weeks.

Comment: @alcor: We don't currently have rules for speech slots. Monitoring the available slots is the first step towards figuring out what rules we need.

Comment: To make this more interesting, our club has started to contract. Yet people still think that we don't have enough speech slots, so I need this measure even more. To complicate it even more, we have a lot of people who abandon speech slots. Usually at the last moment. I'd love to add that to the measurement too.

Comment: I'm still interested in this question.